# How kubectl is more secure than SSH Daemon / access into containers?

Tags: security, kubernetes, ssh, containers, kubectl

Various Kubernetes security recommendations tell you to avoid SSH into containers and ask to use kubectl instead. The prime reason quoted is the possibility of escaping to the underlying host resources via SSH into containers. So, I have following specific queries:

1. Which features of kubectl prevent you to access host resources and why ssh has more risk of accessing host resources as compared to kubectl? How kubectl is more secure?
2. Can SSH skip the Pod Security policies and access/mount paths on the underlying host which are restricted in pod security policy?
3. If SSH into containers is unavoidable, how to secure it in the best possible way?

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is "you can escape via one and not the other", then I think it comes from somebody who don't understand the security mechanisms involved.  There are other reasons to prefer `kubectl exec` over SSH, such as audit logging integrated with everything else Kubernetes, and easy access revocation, but they are possible to get with SSH too. It's just more work

1. kubectl runs client-side. If there were features in it that would prevent you from escaping, you could just patch them out.
2. No, those are on the pod and handled by the underlying kernel. SSH would only get you a shell in the container, just like `kubectl exec` would.
3. Use public-key authentication, make sure to have a strategy for ensuring your software in the container is up-to-date. Think about how you're going to manage the `authorized_keys` file and revocation of compromised SSH keys there. Consider whether you should lock down access to the port SSH is running on with firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks @Tollef. Plz see1. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/security-best-practices-kubernetes-deployment/  _`limit SSH access to Kubernetes nodes, reducing the risk for unauthorized access to host resource`_ 2. https://thenewstack.io/container-security-considerations-kubernetes-deployment/  _`all access to nodes via Kubernetes ensures proper access control & logging. This helps to reduce risk for unauthorized access to host resources`_  I thought ..is thr anythng which can't be done via kubectl exec but allowed via ssh? how ssh cant do access control n logging..yes it wont be centralized?

Comment: ssh access to the _nodes_ is directly to the host, outside any specific container.  Unless you're administering the cluster there's almost never a reason to do that.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you please elaborate _`ssh access to the nodes is directly to the host, outside any specific container`_? If I have SSH daemon running in all containers and I create a k8s service exposed via an external IP to make a SSH connection to a pod behind the k8s service, how that is `outside the container`? Will I be able to escape container isolation and access host resources?

Comment: The links you cited aren't about ssh daemons in containers, they're about directly sshing to the nodes (hosts).

Comment: Yes, probably they are taking about nodes not pods/containers ! Now it's so obvious..accessing nodes via SSH would obviously give access to host resources while kubectl won't .thank you @DavidMaze

Comment: @DavidMaze i know there are several disadvantages of ssh but don't u think, `ssh to pod` has one advantage over `kubectl exec` - u can give user identity with ssh which is not possible with kubectl exec which uses same uid as specified in pod security context . So, any login with kubectl may read all secrets while ssh can restrict that? any way to provide kubectl exec access to user but restricted access to some limited directories inside pod and prohibit reading secrets? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30656 is still open.

Answer (score 1):

Only because you have to run an `ssh` server in your container; thus an extra process running in your container, and have to manage the keys, is enough reason to not want to SSH into a container.

So, that's one drawback. Another one will go with the use case, and it's a risk. Why would you want to SSH into a container? One reason I see is because you want to do it from an external host (without `kubectl` installed and authenticated against `api-server`). So you have to expose an endpoint to outside world, or at least to your network.

Comment: I know that running extra ssh daemon,managing ssh keys is an overhead, ssh would skip k8s auth & audit logging.but  https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/security-best-practices-kubernetes-deployment/ says that `You should limit SSH access to Kubernetes nodes, reducing the risk for unauthorized access to host resource. Instead you should ask users to use “kubectl exec", which will provide direct access to the container environment without the ability to access the host`..I dont understand hw kubectl exec prevents access to host while ssh provides ability to access host?